# visual-studio-code: how to run extension locally on my laptop when connected to another machine with Remote-SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually have a single vscode window on my laptop in which I use the Remote-SSH extension to connect to another machine which hosts the code I'm working on.

At the same time, I have the [Remote VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode&ssr=false#overview) installed locally and want to use it to quickly edit files on other machines I connect to in the terminal (outside of vscode).

However, when I browse extensions in the vscode window which is connected to another machine with Remote-SSH extension, the local extensions (including the Remote VSCode) are greyed out and I cannot seem to enable this extension in vscode on my laptop.

Everything works fine if I just open another vscode window, not connected with Remote-SSH.

How can I also enable/run local extensions when I'm connected to another machine with Remote-SSH?

Installing the extension in question to the remote machine is not an option because it **needs** to be ran locally.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_advanced-forcing-an-extension-to-run-locally-remotely):

Extensions are typically designed and tested to either run locally or remotely, not both. However, if an extension supports it, you can force it to run in a particular location in your settings.json file.

For example, the setting below will force the Docker extension to run locally and Debugger for Chrome extension to run remotely instead of their defaults:

```
"remote.extensionKind": {
    "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker": [ "ui" ],
    "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome": [ "workspace" ]
}
```

A value of "ui" instead of "workspace" will force the extension to run on the local UI/client side instead. Typically, this should only be used for testing unless otherwise noted in the extension's documentation since it can break extensions. See the article on Supporting Remote Development for details.